# sql syntax error while executing dynamic query

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Declare @ColId uniqueidentifier

set @ColId = '1B233EE7-1668-4D03-995F-2D763BF03F06'

EXEC('update custom.location
set siteid =' + @ColId +
'where siteid is null')
```

when execute above sql query get below error-
Incorrect syntax near 'B233EE7'.

Just note that siteid column is of type uniqueidentier.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `''` quotes around `'+@ColId+'`

```
Declare @ColId uniqueidentifier
set @ColId = '1B233EE7-1668-4D03-995F-2D763BF03F06'

EXEC('update t
set id ='''+@colId+'''where id is null')
```

### [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36819/1)

Comment: You'll have to double up your inner quotes to make this work.

Comment: siteid column is of type uniqueidentifier. now  i am getting error- Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @MichaelGreen :yeah you're rite!